# How to add column with header and data to the JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created a class MyTableModel which extends AbstractTableModel. And what I want is, to have already initialized three columns with data? Only with DefaultTableModel I had that option, that I could use a method that takes as a paramater columnName and columnData `addColumn(Object columnName, Object[] columnData)`, so what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you stick with DefaultTableModel? I never needed another TableModel implementation (and can't think of any other situation where that is needed then for dynamically updating tons and tons content that comes from a harddrive or network machine, that cannot be kept in the RAM at one piece).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table model you can have it return anything you want. If you have three `List<String>` or one `List<ThreePropertyPojo>` you just have the table model methods answer correctly:

1. Number of columns is 3
2. Number of rows is `list.size()`
3. Display value for cell (row,col) used `list1.get(row)` (or 2 and 3 depending on 'col') or depending on the value of 'col' you get a particular property from the list element.

That pretty much does it.

There are lots of examples if you Google "java swing tablemodel example"

http://www.javalobby.org/articles/jtable/ has a nice example.

Comment: Well, that's a really nice example. Thank you!